# GDB: Switch to thread when breakpoint is hit

Tags: multithreading, gdb, breakpoints

I set a breakpoint in a multi-threaded inferior. Any of the threads could hit the breakpoint. When the breakpoint is hit, I would like to have gdb switch to the thread that hit it.

Currently, I'm notified that bp is hit. Then I have to look at the top stack frame of every thread to know which one it was, like so:

```
(gdb) info threads
(gdb) thread apply all bt 1 full
(gdb) thread 2
```

I'd like this switching to be automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like this switching to be automatic.

GDB should already do this automatically, see [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/All_002dStop-Mode.html#All_002dStop-Mode):

> Whenever GDB stops your program, due to a breakpoint or a signal, it
> automatically selects the thread where that breakpoint or signal
> happened. GDB alerts you to the context switch with a message such as
> ‘[Switching to Thread n]’ to identify the thread.

Apart from notifying that the breakpoint was hit you should also be notified about switching to another thread.